# Catalina upgrade breaks Henge Stone docking station

Tags: catalina

I have a Late 2016 MBP 15' that I have been using with the Henge Stone dock for almost two years with little to no issues. When upgrading my MBP to Catalina, the Stone dock starting behaving erratically. It does not consistently reconnect USB/Displayport devices when plugged in to the running MBP. It fails much more often than not now. It requires a full reboot of my MBP to work properly.

Anyone else with a Henge Stone experiencing this with Catalina?

Comment: Have you contacted the manufacturer? Perhaps they have a firmware or driver update.

Comment: I created support ticket and in the mean time upgraded firmware to latest.  Same behavior and no response from manufacturer yet